# Squares in p-adic integers

Tags: number-theory

What are the solutions of equation

$$x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2=0,$$

in the $p$-adic integers? I think that for $p = 2$ it has only the trivial solution, but for $p$ odd there are nontrivial solutions.

Comment: I think in this, by modding by $p$ we know that by Chevalley's theorem, this has a solution over $GF(p)$, then apply the general Hensel's lemma, for $p$ odd.

Comment: Correct for $p=2$. In $2$-adics the equation holds $\bmod4$ only if all terms are even or all odd, and except for $w=x=y=z=0$ all even has to imply a not-all-even solution by descent on terminal zeroes base $2$. But the all odd case gives a sum $\not\equiv0\bmod8$.

Comment: For $4n+1$ primes there must be non-trivial solutions because $-1$ will be $p$-adically square and so we can render $y^2=-x^2, w^2=-z^2$.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/149520/96384

Answer (score 3):

Well, there if $x_0^2\equiv a\pmod p$ then there is a solution to $x^2=a$ in $p$-adic solutions. So taking an integer solution $x_0^2+y_0^2+z_0^2+w_0^2=p$, with $x_0\neq 0$, we can find a $p$-adic solution to $x^2+y_0^2+z_0^2+w_0^2=p$.

We can certainly find infinitely many different answers by mutliplying $(x,y_0,z_0,w_0)$ by any $p$-adic number, but the real question is how many projective solutions.

Comment: Not quite enough, the derivative of the function has to be non-zero for Hensel's lifting to work, so $2(x_0 + y_0 + z_0 + w_0)$ has to be nonzero for your solution mod $p.$

Comment: @Igor: Just $2x_0$: the others are constants with respect to $x$.

Comment: Yes you need $x_0\not\equiv 0\pmod p$, but at least one of the $x_0,y_0,z_0,w_0$ is non-zero and hence non-zero modulo $p$. @IgorRivin

Comment: Ah, OK, that's slightly different from what I thought...

Answer (score 3):

This answer may be disproportionate to the context of the question, *but*, if by chance one knows about local behavior of quaternion algebras... one might recognize that quaternary quadratic form as being the norm-form of the (usual rational form of) the Hamiltonian quaternions. The only ramified places (at which that quaternion algebra remains a division algebra) are $2$ and $\mathbb R$. Thus, at all odd $p$ that form is isotropic, and at $2$ (and $\mathbb R$, obviously) it is anisotropic.

(Yes, certainly, Hensel's lemma is used in setting up the usual properties of  division algebras over local fields, as in Weil's "Basic Number Theory". Also, my on-line notes at http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/algebra/algebras.pdf do things similar to Weil, ...)

Comment: Actually related (what happens above $2$): https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3965273/96384