# Over which extensions of $\mathbb Q_2$ is $X^2+Y^2+Z^2$ isotropic?

Tags: extension-field, quadratic-forms, p-adic-number-theory

I was playing around a bit with quadratic forms for a different question here, and among other things had to decide when the form $X^2+Y^2+Z^2$ is isotropic over a certain field $k$, i.e. whether there is $(0,0,0) \neq (x,y,z) \in k \times k \times k$ such that $x^2+y^2+z^2=0$. This is trivially the case if $k$ contains a square root of $-1$, giving a positive answer for $k$ being any $p$-adic field $\mathbb Q_p$ with $p \equiv 1$ mod $4$, and hence all extensions of those too. Playing around a bit with Hensel's Lemma (and, funnily, using that $-1$ is *not* a square) led me to believe the form is isotropic over all $\mathbb Q_p$ with $p \equiv 3$ mod $4$ as well. As far as $p$-adic fields go, this left the case of extensions of $\mathbb Q_2$.

Here, I think I have an argument that the form has no nontrivial zeroes i.e. is **an**isotropic over $\mathbb Q_2$ itself. So next I went to its [seven distinct quadratic extensions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/113399/96384). I found the form is isotropic by coming up with individual solutions over $\mathbb Q_2(\sqrt d)$ for $d=-1, -3, -5, -2, -6, -10$: i.e. all the quadratic extensions *except* $\mathbb Q_2(\sqrt 2)$. <s>For this one, I believe it is still anisotropic.</s> (Edit: Thanks to the Keith Conrad's answer, I no longer believe this.)

**Question 1**: Are my results so far correct? (Edit: As just said, the form is actually isotropic over each of the seven quadratic extensions of $\mathbb Q_2$.)

**Question 2**: Are there easier criteria to decide the question for further extensions of $\mathbb Q_2$? <s>In particular, if the results are correct, for which quadratic extensions of $\mathbb Q_2(\sqrt 2)$ is the form isotropic? Also, is there any high-brow explanation why the field extension $\mathbb Q_2(\sqrt 2)$ is singled out here? (I mean, if the unramified $\mathbb Q_2(\sqrt{-3})$ had behaved differently from the others, that would not have surprised me, but this ...?)</s>

I am aware and know the absolute basics of the theory of Witt groups (or Witt rings), but not enough to be able to apply them here. But I'm happy to learn if somebody can tell me how to apply that machinery here. (I know just enough to guess that the residue characteristic of $2$ here will complicate things.)

*Added*: There is a theorem of Witt's which I am comfortable with, which says that all quadratic forms in $\ge 5$ variables are isotropic over any $p$-adic field. For a field extension $K \vert \mathbb Q_p$ of degree $n$, it is therefore tempting to express a quadratic form in $d$ variables (here, $d=3$) over $K$ as one in $nd$ variables over $\mathbb Q_p$, however the algebra of the field extension introduces some relations between the coefficients which effectively reduce the number of variables again. Still it seems as if at least in many cases, a "big" enough extension should give us enough variables to just rely on that theorem. I don't have the mindpower to think through this right now, but again would be happy to learn if that works.

Comment: For $p\equiv 3\bmod 4$: if every $x^2+y^2$ is a square $\bmod p$ then $x^2$ is a square implies $x^2+1$ is a square thus every $a\bmod p$ is a square, contradiction. Thus $x^2+y^2=-z^2\bmod p$ has a solution which lifts to $\Bbb{Z}_p$.

Comment: @reuns: That's a nice streamlined version of the argument I had in mind for that case, thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When $K$ is a field not of characteristic $2$, being able to solve $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 0$ nontrivially in $K$ is equivalent to being able to solve $x^2 + y^2 = -1$ in $K$, so I will think of the problem from that point of view.

I have checked explicitly that this can be done when $K$ is a quadratic extension of $\mathbf Q_2$ other than $\mathbf Q_2(\sqrt{2})$, as you say you did, and it can *also* be done when $K = \mathbf Q_2(\sqrt{2})$.

I'll list all seven quadratic extensions of $\mathbf Q_2$ in the order you did:
$$
\mathbf Q_2(\sqrt{-1}), \
\mathbf Q_2(\sqrt{-3}), \
\mathbf Q_2(\sqrt{-5}), \
\mathbf Q_2(\sqrt{-2}), \
\mathbf Q_2(\sqrt{-6}), \
\mathbf Q_2(\sqrt{-10}), \
\mathbf Q_2(\sqrt{2}). 
$$
In the four fields $\mathbf Q_2(\sqrt{-1})$,
$\mathbf Q_2(\sqrt{-5})$,
$\mathbf Q_2(\sqrt{-2})$, and
$\mathbf Q_2(\sqrt{-10}),$
it is very easy to see a solution to $x^2 + y^2 = -1$:
$$
0^2 + \sqrt{-1}^2, \ 
2^2 + \sqrt{-5}^2, \ 
1^2 + \sqrt{-2}^2, \ 
3^2 + \sqrt{-10}^2.
$$

In $\mathbf Q_2(\sqrt{-3})$ we have a cube root of unity
$\zeta_3 = (-1 + \sqrt{-3})/2$, for which $1 + \zeta_3 + \zeta_3^2 = 0$, so
$$
-1 = \zeta_3 + \zeta_3^2 = \zeta_3^4 + \zeta_3^2.
$$

In $\mathbf Q_2(\sqrt{-6})$, after playing around a bit I got
$$
\left(\frac{2+\sqrt{-6}}{2}\right)^2 + 
\left(\frac{2-\sqrt{-6}}{2}\right)^2 = -1.
$$

That leaves us with $\mathbf Q_2(\sqrt{2})$, whose ring of integers is $\mathbf Z_2[\sqrt{2}]$.  I am not going to record here all the numerical work I did (by hand), but just report the final result: we can write
$$
-1 = x^2 + (\sqrt{2} + 2)^2
$$
for some $x \in \mathbf Z_2[\sqrt{2}]$ where $x \equiv 1 \bmod \sqrt{2}^3$. This follows from Hensel's lemma on $\mathbf Q_2(\sqrt{2})$ for the polynomial $f(X) = X^2 + 1 + (\sqrt{2}+2)^2 = X^2 + 7 + 4\sqrt{2}$:
$$
f(1) = 8 + 4\sqrt{2} \Longrightarrow |f(1)|_2 = \frac{1}{4\sqrt{2}}
$$
and
$$
f'(1) = 2 \Longrightarrow |f'(1)|_2^2 = \frac{1}{4}.
$$
Since $|f(1)|_2 < |f'(1)|_2^2$, Hensel's lemma tells us there is a unique solution to $f(x) = 0$ where $x \in \mathbf Z_2[\sqrt{2}]$ and
$|x - 1|_2 < |f'(1)|_2 = 1/2$, or equivalently $x \equiv 1 \bmod (\sqrt{2}^3)$. A more precise form of Hensel's lemma tells us that $|x - 1|_2 = |f(1)/f'(1)|_2 = (1/4\sqrt{2})/(1/2) = 1/2\sqrt{2} = 1/\sqrt{2}^3$, so $x \not\equiv 1 \bmod \sqrt{2}^4$.

We can compute $x$ using the binomial series for the square root:
$$
x = (-7 - 4\sqrt{2})^{1/2} = (1 - 4\sqrt{2} - 8)^{1/2}
$$
so
$$
x = \sum_{n \geq 0} \binom{1/2}{n}(-4\sqrt{2}-8)^n = 1 + \sum_{n \geq 1} \binom{1/2}{n}(-1)^n(4\sqrt{2}+8)^n
$$
Since ${\rm ord}_2\binom{1/2}{n} = -2n + s_2(n)$, where $s_2(n)$ is the sum of the base $2$ digits of $n$, and ${\rm ord}_2((4\sqrt{2}+8)^n) = 5n/2$, the $n$th term of the series
has $2$-adic valuation $5n/2 - 2n + s_2(n) = n/2 + s_2(n)$, so its  $\pi$-adic valuation ($\pi = \sqrt{2}$ over the $2$-adics) is twice that: $n + 2s_2(n)$.  Since $n+2s_2(n) \geq 7$  for all $n \geq 1$ other than $n = 1$, $2$, and $4$,
$$
x \equiv 1  + \sum_{n = 1, 2, 4} \binom{1/2}{n}(-1)^n(4\sqrt{2}+8)^n \bmod \pi^7\mathbf Z_2[\pi].
$$
Working this out modulo $\pi^7$,
$$
x \equiv 1 + \pi^3 + \pi^5 + \pi^6 \bmod \pi^7\mathbf Z_2[\pi].
$$
In "normal" notation, with $\pi = \sqrt{2}$, this approximate root of $f(X)$ is $9+6\sqrt{2} \bmod 8\sqrt{2}\mathbf Z_2[\sqrt{2}]$. As a check,
$$
(9 + 6\sqrt{2})^2 + (7 + 4\sqrt{2}) = 160 + 112\sqrt{2} = 16\sqrt{2}(5\sqrt{2} + 7), 
$$
which is a multiple of $\pi^7 = 8\sqrt{2}$.

In what way did your work suggest that there might not be a solution to $x^2 + y^2 = -1$ in $\mathbf Q_2(\sqrt{2})$?

There is a high-brow explanation for why we found a solution in the particular quadratic extension $\mathbf Q_2(\sqrt{2})$. Being able to solve $x^2 + y^2 = -1$  in a local field $F$ (not of characteristic $2$) is the same as saying the Hilbert symbol $(-1,-1)_F$ is $1$ rather than $-1$. Letting $F = \mathbf Q(\sqrt{2})_v$ be a completion of $\mathbf Q(\sqrt{2})$, Hilbert reciprocity says the number of $v$ such that $(-1,-1)_{\mathbf Q_2(\sqrt{2})_v}$ is $-1$ is even.  When $v$ is a place of odd residue field characteristic, $\mathbf Q(\sqrt{2})_v$ is a local field that is an extension of $\mathbf Q_p$ for an odd prime $p$, so that Hilbert symbol is $1$ since we can already solve $x^2 + y^2 = -1$ in $\mathbf Q_p$ (and actually in $\mathbf Z_p$). That leaves us with just three remaining places $v$ on $\mathbf Q(\sqrt{2})$: the two real places (corresponding to the two different embeddings of $\mathbf Q(\sqrt{2})$ into $\mathbf R$) and the unique place over $2$, corresponding to the prime $(\sqrt{2})$ in $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{2}]$.
We obviously can't solve $x^2 + y^2 = -1$ in $\mathbf R$, so
the Hilbert symbol $(-1,-1)_{\mathbf Q(\sqrt{2})_v}$ is $-1$ when $v$ is a real place. That leaves us with just one more place, over $2$, and since the Hilbert symbol is $-1$ at an even number of places it *must* be $1$ at the place over $2$.

By similar reasoning, if $K$ is an arbitrary real quadratic field, we can describe the non-archimedean places $v$ for which $x^2 + y^2 = -1$ has a solution in $K_v$:

(1) If $v$ lies over an odd prime then there is a solution in $K_v$ since there already is one in $\mathbf Q_p$ for all odd $p$, and $K_v$ contains some $\mathbf Q_p$.

(2) If $v$ lies over $2$ and $2$ does not split completely in $K$, then there is just one $2$-adic place on $K$. We *can* solve $x^2 + y^2 = -1$ in $K_v$ by Hilbert reciprocity because we can solve it in every other completion except the two real completions, and two is even but three is not.

(3) If $v$ lies over $2$ and $2$ splits completely in $K$ then we *can't* solve $x^2 + y^2 = -1$ in $K_v$ since $K_v \cong \mathbf Q_2$.

If $K$ is an arbitrary imaginary quadratic field, we can also determine the non-archimedean $v$ for which $x^2 + y^2 = -1$ has a solution in $K_v$:

(1) If $v$ lies over an odd prime then there is a solution in $K_v$ for the same reason as in the real quadratic case above.

(2) If $v$ lies over $2$ and $2$ does not split completely in $K$, then there is exactly one $2$-adic place on $K$. There is also exactly one archimedean place, with completion $\mathbf C$. We can  solve $x^2 + y^2 = -1$ in $\mathbf C$, so Hilbert reciprocity implies  we *can* solve $x^2 + y^2 = -1$ in $K_v$.  In other words, we can solve $x^2 + y^2 = -1$ in every completion of $K$, so by Hasse-Minkowski we can solve $x^2 + y^2 = -1$ in $K$.

(3) If $v$ lies over $2$ and $2$ splits completely in $K$ then we *can't* solve $x^2 + y^2 = -1$ in $K_v$ since $K_v \cong \mathbf Q_2$.

The second item of each list for real and imaginary quadratic fields explains why we found solutions in every quadratic extension of $\mathbf Q_2$ other than $\mathbf Q_2(\sqrt{2})$ without needing to work in the completion itself (i.e., a solution in $\mathbf Q(i)$, $\mathbf Q(\sqrt{-3})$, and so on): you wrote every quadratic extension of $\mathbf Q_2$ other than $\mathbf Q_2(\sqrt{2})$ as a $2$-adic completion of an imaginary quadratic field, and in the imaginary quadratic fields that you chose, you can check that $2$ does not split completely (sometimes $2$ ramifies, sometimes $2$ is inert, but $2$ never splits completely).  In the case of $\mathbf Q_2(\sqrt{2})$, we can write it as $\mathbf Q_2(\sqrt{-14})$, a completion of $\mathbf Q(\sqrt{-14})$ at its unique $2$-adic place.
Then results above say we have to be to solve $x^2 + y^2 = -1$ in $\mathbf Q(\sqrt{-14})$, and in fact a solution is $x = (2+3\sqrt{-14})/10$ and $y = (6-\sqrt{-14})/10$.

More generally, if $\mathbf Q_2(\sqrt{2}) = \mathbf Q_2(\sqrt{d})$ for some integer $d$ then ${\rm ord}_2(d) = 1$, so $\mathbf Q(\sqrt{d})$ ramifies at $2$ and thus there is a unique $2$-adic place on $\mathbf Q(\sqrt{d})$, so for $d < 0$ we'd be in the same situation as $\mathbf Q(\sqrt{-14})$: there will be a solution to $x^2 + y^2 = -1$ in $\mathbf Q(\sqrt{d})$.

Comment: good................

Comment: Wonderful, that's all I could hope for. The solutions for the six easy cases I came up with are exactly (up to scaling in the $-6$ case) the ones you got, including that funny cube root of unity. Now I wonder just a little why the case $\sqrt{2}$ appears to be more difficult, or formally: why, unlike in the other cases where solutions are found already in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{d}]$, we seem to need the completion.

Comment: As for why I believed there was no solution over $\mathbb Q_2(\sqrt2)$: I wrote down series expansions $x= x_0 + x_1 \pi +x_2 \pi^2 + ...$ and $y = y_0 + y_1 \pi +y_2 \pi^2 + ...$ (of course $\pi = \sqrt 2$) and tried to iteratively solve for coefficients with $x^2+y^2=-1$. I thought I got as far as $x_3, y_3$ and something suggested a contradiction, but your proof shows I was wrong (and, as usual, I should have relied on Hensel to get actually working coefficients).

Comment: I added an explanation about why you'll always find a solution in an imaginary quadratic field. The "problem" with $\mathbf Q_2(\sqrt{2})$ is that you write it as a completion of the real quadratic field $\mathbf Q(\sqrt{2})$, where of course you can never have a global solution (obviously there's no solution in $\mathbf R$, hence none in $\mathbf Q(\sqrt{2})$).  By writing $\mathbf Q_2(\sqrt{2})$ as a $2$-adic completion of an imaginary quadratic field, such as $\mathbf Q(\sqrt{-14})$, you'll have a global solution to $x^2 + y^2 = -1$ in the field without needing to use the completion.

Comment: Ah! Being so trained in local and so little in global thinking, in my notes I switched between $2$ and $-14$ seamlessly, and for the post here I just settled on $2$ there because it felt simpler. But of course all the (global) examples I had found in the other six cases "came from" the "imaginary" square roots (thus I left them in my post): now I see I should have just tried a little harder for an example with $\sqrt{-14}$ in it, and the whole seeming singularity of that case would have disappeared. But oh well, that made you put in the extra explanation for that. Thank you very much!

Comment: Not all solutions, except in $\mathbf Q_2(\sqrt{2})$, were found in $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{d}]$, but in $\mathbf Q(\sqrt{d})$.  Hasse-Minkowski is a theorem about solvability over fields, not rings of integers. I suspect, but have not checked for certain, that there is not a solution to $x^2 + y^2 = -1$ in $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{-6}]$ and perhaps not in $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{-3}]$ either.

Comment: I was still thinking in terms of solutions of $x^2+y^2+z^2=0$, where we can scale into integer rings without problem. -- Last question: Is there anything to say about higher degree extensions (obviously we're done with those that contain quadratic extensions now)?

Comment: Computing the Hilbert symbol for $2$-adic fields is tricky since this is the case of a wild symbol. I am not aware of a general formula. Search for “wild 2-adic symbol” for example. Special cases are discussed in Neukirch’s class field theory book and Fesenko and Vostokov’s book on local fields.

Comment: @KCd: I think I could deal with the remaining case now, and I think the process also gives a general, "purely local" reason why the form became isotropic over all the quadratic extensions. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by Keith Conrad's great answer, I was finally able to answer the question in the title, including the case of wild ramification. A great help was [this recent preprint by Bill Casselman](https://personal.math.ubc.ca/%7Ecass/research/pdf/QuadraticCFT.pdf), spelling out class field theory for quadratic extensions of $p$-adic fields and not shying away from the case of wild ramification. -- Let $K\vert \mathbb Q_2$ be a finite extension.

**Claim:** The form $X^2+Y^2+Z^2$ is isotropic over $K$ ($\Leftrightarrow$ $-1$ is a sum of two (or less) squares in $K$ $\Leftrightarrow$ the [Stufe (level, niveau)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stufe_(algebra)) of $K$ is $\le 2$ $\Leftrightarrow$ the [Hilbert symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_symbol) $(-1, -1)_K$ is $1$ $\Leftrightarrow$ the quaternion algebra $\left(\dfrac{-1, -1}{K}\right)$ is split) **if and only if $n = [K:\mathbb Q_2]$ is even**.

**Proof**: Direction "$\Rightarrow$": Assume the form is isotropic. The quaternion algebra $\left(\dfrac{-1,-1}{K}\right) \simeq \left(\dfrac{-1,-1}{\mathbb Q_2}\right)\otimes K$ is a skew field iff the form is anisotropic over $K$; but if $K$ splits $D := \left(\dfrac{-1,-1}{\mathbb Q_2}\right)$, then by definition $D\otimes K \simeq M_{2\times 2}(K)$ whose simple module has $D$-dimension $\frac{n}{2}$ which therefore has to be an integer. [Generalisations of this: A) if $K\vert k$ with $[K:k]=n$ is a splitting field for a $k$-central division algebra $D$ with $\sqrt{\dim_k D}=d$, then $d$ divides $n$; B) a theorem conjectured by Witt (based on our ternary case well-known to him) and proven independently by Artin and Springer (cf. section 1.5 in [B. Kahn: *Formes Quadratiques Sur Un Corps*](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/%7Ebruno.kahn/preprints/fqbook3.pdf); also [this question and answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/307753/96384)) saying that *any* anisotropic quadratic form remains anisotropic over field extensions of odd degree.]

Direction "$\Leftarrow$": Now assume $n$ is even. Let $n=ef$ with $e$ and $f$ being, respectively, the absolute ramification index and inertia degree of $K$ over $\mathbb Q_2$. In case $f$ is even, the residue field of $K$ contains $\mathbb F_{4}$, so $K$ contains a primitive third root of unity $\zeta_3$, and $-1 = \zeta_3^2 +(\zeta_3^2)^2$.

So w.l.o.g. from now on we *assume $e$ to be even*. Also w.l.o.g we can assume that $-1$ is not a square in $K$ i.e. $L := K(\sqrt{-1})$ is a quadratic extension. Now our goal is to show that $-1$ is in the image of the norm map $N_{L\vert K}$.

Denote by $\mathfrak p_L$ and $\mathfrak p_K$ the respective prime ideals of the integer rings $\mathcal{O}_L$ and $\mathcal{O}_K$; and by $U^{(i)}_K$ (resp. $U^{(i)}_L$) the standard filtration steps of the respective principal units. Because $-1 \equiv 1 \pmod 2$ we have $-1 \in U^{(e)}_K$. Now if $e$ is even, one can multiply this through with an appropriate square of the form $(1+x \pi_K^{e/2})^2$ so that "modulo squares, we move $-1$ up to $U^{(e+1)}_K$" i.e. $L=K(\sqrt{-1})=K(\sqrt\alpha)$ for some $\alpha \in U^{(e+1)}_K$, compare the procedure on p.4 of [Casselman](https://personal.math.ubc.ca/%7Ecass/research/pdf/QuadraticCFT.pdf).

In fact, with that procedure we are led to two possible cases for $\alpha$:

- Either $\alpha \in U_K^{(2e)}$ in which case $L\vert K$ is unramified, and the norm is well-known to be surjective on units of the integer rings, so we are done. (This case [can happen](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4609011/96384).)

In fact, that is the idea to finish even in the remaining, ramified case: $-1$ is still in a high enough filtration step, where the norm is surjective.

- Or $\alpha \in U_K^{(2k+1)} \setminus U_K^{(2k+2)}$ with $k <e$. Then the different ideal is generated by $\frac{2}{\pi_K^k}$. Since we know from above that $k$ here is $\ge e/2$, setting $r:=e-k$ the *different ideal is of the form $\mathfrak p_K^r = \mathfrak p_L^{2r}$ with some $0 <r \le e/2$*, cf. [Casselman 3.4.](https://personal.math.ubc.ca/%7Ecass/research/pdf/QuadraticCFT.pdf). "Higher principal units give bigger different ideals".

But in this case it is known that the restriction of the norm map to high enough principal units, namely,

$$N_{L\vert K} : U_L^{(2r)} \rightarrow U_K^{(2r)}$$

is surjective ([Casselman prop 4.4.](https://personal.math.ubc.ca/%7Ecass/research/pdf/QuadraticCFT.pdf), his $m$ is our $r$; cf. [Fesenko/Vostokov III 1.4/1.5](https://ivanfesenko.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/vol.pdf) pp.70 et seq., their $s$ computes in our case as $2r-1$; cf. also Serre, *Local Fields*, V §3 prop. 5(iv); his $t$ also computes as $2r-1$ in our case, consistent with his calculation of the different in lemma 3). In particular, since $2r \le e$, every element of $U^{(e)}_K$ is a norm. That includes $-1$.

(Going through the argument one sees that in case $e$ odd one can only conclude that all elements in $U^{(e+1)}_K$ are norms, and $-1$ is not contained in that.)

References:

Casselman, B.: [Local Quadratic Extensions](https://personal.math.ubc.ca/%7Ecass/research/pdf/QuadraticCFT.pdf), preprint, 2023

Fesenko/Vostokov: [Local Fields and Their Extensions](https://ivanfesenko.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/vol.pdf), Second edition 2002, online version